# Array of the hashes: insert or append the value

Tags: python

I have an array of hashes:

```
main_hash = [
    {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': [
            {'key3': 11, 'key4': ['val4', 'val44', 'val444']},
            {'key3': 22, 'key4': ['val42', 'val442', 'val4442']}
        ]
  }, 
  {
        'key1': 'value2',
        'key2': [
            {'key3': 44, 'key4': ['val43', 'val443', 'val4443']},
            {'key3': 55, 'key4': [.......]},
            {'key3': 66, 'key4': [....]}
        ]
  }, 
]
```

How I easily check if 'key3' with a certain value already exists in `key2` and then append a value to 'key4', other just insert a new value:

```
{'key3': 123, 'key4': ['new value val4']}
or
{'key3': 22, 'key4': ['val42', 'val442', 'val4442', 'val9999']}
```

I can find a value using the `filter` but I can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: Already exists where? In a given item in the array or anywhere in the array? Off topic, it really seems like these should be instances of a class that expose the behavior you want as a method.

Comment: You have multiple `key3`, can they have duplicate values?

Comment: Are the various `"key"` strings always going to be the same in every dictionary within this data structure? If so, I'd suggest dropping them out of the dictionary and simply mapping from `value1` to dictionaries mapping from `int` to `list` (of value4s). Your example data structure would become `{"value1": {11: ["val4", "val44", "val444"], 22: ["val42", "val442", "val4442"]}, "value2": {44: ["val43", "val443", "val4443"], 55: [...], 66:[...]}}`. This doesn't directly answer your question, but having the numbers mapped to by `"key3"` be keys, rather than values will make solving it easier.

Comment: @Blckknght, that's my next question. Why is it better?

Comment: Well, your question is about how to find if a specific `key3` value is present in the data structure. That's easy in a dictionary `if some_value in some_dict`. If instead you need to check if it is a value mapped by some key in a list of dicts, you need to iterate over all the dicts, checking the value in each one (`any(d["some_key"] == value for d in list_of dicts)`).

Comment: @Blckknght, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious..why can't you do this ?

```
for d in main_hash:
 for smalld in d['key2']:
    print('key3',  smalld['key3'])

    if smalld['key3']>30:
        smalld['key4'].append('Greater than 10')
```

Another alternative could be to user operator.itemgetter, however I don't see any improvement or clarity with that approach ...